# Hibernate injection: How to inject hibernate annotated classes defined in other project inside a SpringMVC project?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations, code-injection

I have two projects: one of them contains the annotated classes modeling the database that I'll be using in the second project. The second is a SpringMVC project; in one of the servlets defined, I have the datasource, the hibernateproperties and the annotatedClasses (from the 1st project) listed inside my SessionFactory Bean.

However, when I try to run the project, I receive an excpetion about not-finding the annotated classes. When I move the classes to inside the 2nd project, everything runs perfectly.

How should I declare the annotated classes to correctly inject them in the second project?

Servlet:

...

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>kent.project.universe.Component</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

...

My component class:

```
package kent.project.universe;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "component")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_comp", sequenceName = "seq_comp")
public class Component implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5925196638850471023L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "component_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_comp")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Double quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "measure_id")
    private Measure measure;

    @Column(name = "position")
    private Integer position;

    //getters and setters ommited

}
```

Thank you!!

**UPDATED - 5/10/14**

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [kent.project.universe.Component]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [kent.project.universe.Component]
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:467)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:499)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:493)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1371)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>       ... 21 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [kent.project.universe.Component]
>       at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.ClassEditor.setAsText(ClassEditor.java:63)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:416)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:388)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:427)
>       at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:447)
>       ... 27 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kent.project.universe.Component
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>       at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
>       at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:290)
>       ... 35 more

I believe that the problem consists in the order that the dependencies are loaded. In Eclipse's interface, the classes imported exists. However, when the project runs and an attempt to load the hibernate annotade class is made, tha classes cannot be found.

**UPDATED - 15/10/14**

I'm using Maven. The build descriptor for the first:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

for the second project:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <version>0.0.1</version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace you are receiving?

Comment: @geoand Hey, I posted the stacktrace. Do you have any idea??

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle for dependency management? If so, what does your build script look like?

Comment: @geoand I'm using Maven. Just added the build descriptor

Comment: Thanks! Could you also provide the dependencies you are using?